# How to Add multiple versions of the same library Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have a situation here. because of some new Feature updates, I had to upgrade LIBRARY1-1.10.0 to a new version.

So In my dependency, I added
implementation project(':LIBRARY1-1.20.0.0'), which uses picasso:2.71828 -> Works fine ()

problem is I've another Dependency (LIBRARY2 -1.0), which needs picasso:2.5.2. (As this version has a deprecated API use Picasso.into, which got changed in the new version to Picasso.get).

I'm wondering how I can keep multiple dependencies in my gradle so I can use both 3rd party modules.

Comment: Instead of demo example can you explain your requirements and problems with read code?

Answer (score 0):

Since, the old method of Picasso is deprecated, try to find a solution for using a workaround on the Picasso doc.

Also, u cant use two libraries and even if u use it, the compiler will ignore the old version and will accept the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to below discussion  - 
[get-multiple-versions-of-the-same-library](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-get-multiple-versions-of-the-same-library/7400)

you can use like below -

```
   dependencies {
      compile5 'LIBRARY1:5.0.0'
      compile6 'LIBRARY1:6.0.0'
    }
```

above download two versions, while compiling with only one version

you can can through below link for conflict resolution -

[Dependency management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html)

In case of conflict, Gradle by default uses the newest of conflicting versions. However, you can change this behavior. Use this method to configure the resolution to fail eagerly on any version conflict, e.g. multiple different versions of the same dependency (group and name are equal) in the same Configuration.
[ResolutionStrategy](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html)

Hope this helps.